# How to create sub-menu (select) that opens horizontally on hover with ng-animate?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, bootstrap-4, ng-animate

I have 2 states of rows where each row contains 2 columns:

1) 1st state is when mouse cursor is NOT hovered on the first column (menu)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
       Active button 
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9"> 
       <input type="search" ng-model="directionsSearch" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

2) 2nd state is when mouse hovered on the first column (menu) and the menu is expanded

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"> 
        Button 1 | Button 2 | Button 3 | Button 4 | Button 5  
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
        <input type="search" ng-model="directionsSearch" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

As you could see those sizes of columns are changing in different states and I would like to make this transformation smoothly by using ng-animate

How could I implement it?